How do i run a stop a test if a certain condition is met in Tosca?
im currently trying to do error handling on my script, was thinking if a certain error message was verified successfully, the whole test case will stop immediately, is there a way for this to happen?
Im using if/else statements, if the described error message is present, stop the while test immediately.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
